# Creating TAP device fails IOCTL returns file descriptor in bad state

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I'm following a couple guides here, namely this one https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt and this one https://www.saminiir.com/lets-code-tcp-ip-stack-1-ethernet-arp/

However I can't seem to get my code to function. Running the following snippet prints `IOCTL call failed: File descriptor in bad state`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/if_tun.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int tun_alloc(char *dev) {
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int fd, err;
    if( (fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)) < 0 ) {
        puts("Failed to open TAP device");
        return -1;
    }
    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    /* Flags: IFF_TUN   - TUN device (no Ethernet headers) 
     *        IFF_TAP   - TAP device  
     *
     *        IFF_NO_PI - Do not provide packet information  
     */ 
    ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TAP | IFF_NO_PI;
    if(*dev) {
        strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, IFNAMSIZ);
    }

    if( (err = ioctl(fd, 'T', (void *) &ifr)) < 0 ) {
        perror("IOCTL call failed");
        close(fd);
        return err;
    }
    strcpy(dev, ifr.ifr_name);

    return fd;
}   

int main(void) {
    int fd = tun_alloc("my tuntap");
    if (fd < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    getchar();
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

For reference I'm on Fedora 38 running kernel 6.2.15-300.fc38.x86_64. Running the same code with the `'T'` in the ioctl call being replaced with `TUNSETIFF` requires root permission and returns `IOCTL call failed: Invalid argument`

Comment: Aside: The cast to `void *` is not needed. And `memset()` can be replaced with `struct ifreq ifr = {0};` That `t` is quite suspicious.

Comment: The second parameter to the `ioctl` call should be *TUNSETIFF*, not enclosed in quotes. It's a constant, not a string. Also, try using a devname without a space.

Comment: @JoelC that seemed to do the trick, using TUNSETIFF wasn't working before but using TUNSETIFF and having no spaces in the name seems to do the trick.

Comment: `strcpy(dev, ifr.ifr_name);` invokes undefined behaviour, because `"my tuntap"` is a read-only string literal.

Comment: @pmacfarlane good catch! I didn't consider that when I copied the example code